# SSRS report and performance point filter issue in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, reporting-services, performancepoint, sql-server-2012, dashboard-designer-2013

1. Deployed a dashboard in a sharepoint site
2. this dashboard it has a Performance point filter which is get data from report database
3. and it has a performance point report it is connected with a report from ssrs report library in a sharepoint  site, this report in SSRS report library deployed using visual studio .
   when connect a performance point report to ssrs report we used sharepoint integration mode and using sharepoint reporting services.

The problem is:

after deploy the dashboard and in sharepoint page when we select all options from performancepoint filter data not loaded in ssrs report and gives the error message.

Comment: What is the error message? I assume your report has one parameter with multiple options. Is it working for a single option?

Comment: it is works for a single option; error message: • Issue when trying to select more number of items in PerformancePoint filter with Reporting Services Report 
This causes error: the report is missing a parameter value.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that myself. Performance point only wants to bind a single value. The commas in the string that come with multiple values cause the problem. You can get similar problems with SQL and the 'IN' operator and parameters. If they want to use multiple selections don't bind the report to a performance point filter, just let the user select using the report web part. You can set the default using reporting services user interface in SharePoint